# Implement F=ab+a'c+b'c' using AND/OR and no NOT

Tags: boolean-algebra

Implement  F=ab+a'c+b'c' using only AND/OR gates. And we do not have any inverterad signals to use (guess that means we have to make the inverterad signals from our AND/OR gates.

But I'm just stuck. Should I try using K-map, because that just gives me an even longer expression.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is not possible. If $a,b,c$ are all false, then any formula using only AND and OR evaluates false, but $F$ evaluates true.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this exercise could be to demonstrate, that the combination of `AND` and `OR` is not [functional complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness). Every Boolean expression can be implemented using `AND` and `NOT`. `OR` and `NOT` are also sufficient.

The [Karnaugh-Veitch map](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/):

[image]